# jquery .html() doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I am using jquery .html() to append some  tags dynamically by calling a REST url, but it doesn't work.

```
<div style="display: none;" id="tables">
    <form:select id="table" name="table" path="table">      
        <form:option value="">Choose</form:option>
        <div id="tables-select">
        <!-- The available tables for update will be added here -->
        </div>
    </form:select>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getTables(type) {
            $.getJSON('/web/tables/db/' + type,
            {
                ajax : 'true'
            },function(data) {
            html ='';
            var len = data.length;
            for ( var i=0; i<len; i++) {
               html += '<option value="'+data[i]+'" >'+data[i]+'</option>';
            }
            $('#tables-select').html(html);
            });
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

I see the REST call is going through, but nothing is happening.
After debugging and placing break points, I see that the java script jumps from line 10 directly to end of java script function (line 20).

Any idea what is happening here?
I have bunch of same kind of functions in my page and all those work expect for this one.

EDIT:

This is how I am calling the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#type").live('change', function(){
            var type = $(this).val();
            getSites(type);
            getTabless(type);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please indent your code to make it more readable. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't include line numbers in your code, it messes up the formatting.

Comment: Put a break point on line 15. If you're not hitting that, then the AJAX call is not functioning correctly.

Comment: did you place a breakpoint in the callback function?

Comment: so my answer got downvoted for some reason you are also missing "<script" in your code. and dude leave harry potter alone !

Comment: sorry for bad indentation and missing "<script" is a typo in post, not in code.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, this code is wrong: there's a missing close brace for `getTables()`. Also, I assume you have some code somewhere that actually **calls** `getTables()`, otherwise this code does nothing except declare a function.

When debugging, the `$.getJSON` call will indeed execute quickly. The whole purpose of AJAX is that it is **asynchronous**. The debugger will thus step over the `$.getJSON` call without entering the callback, because the callback is invoked at a later time. If you put a breakpoint inside the callback then it should be triggered.

This whole `<DIV>` has a style of `display:none`. Unless you are somewhere calling `$('#tables').show()` or otherwise doing something to make it visible, then the result won't ever be visible, except in the DOM, or via a tool like firebug.

Also, you cannot put a `<DIV>` tag inside a `<SELECT>` tag. Either use an `<OPTGROUP>` tag for the `tables-select` element, or replace the whole contents of the `<SELECT>` element, including the initial "Choose" option.

Comment: yes, I do have a function on top of the page that calls the getTables() and as I said the REST call is going through fine and I see results in browser, after that step the debugger just skips to last line of function. The missing brace is a typo.

Comment: The debugger **will** skip to the last line of the function, because the callback is asynchronous.

Comment: removing ajax true will make it a synchronous call ?

Comment: @voldemort ajax true is just a property of the `data` parameter and has nothing to do with how the method behaves. I strongly recommend you back up a couple steps and break your problem down into smaller chunks. Aside from the `JSTL` tags you have your code seems OK so I would start by removing that factor.

Comment: I made some progress on breaking up the problem. I removed the html+= '....' and placed an alert to see whether data is really reaching the javascript variable and it does and alerts me for every table I have. Now I think the issue is with the div tag sitting in middle of a <select>. I will try to replace JSTL tags with html and see how it goes

Comment: @voldemort that's great, it's easy to get ahead of ourselves sometimes. Good Luck!